# How to get updated iframe source

Tags: iframe

How can i get the updated iframe src value after my user navigates throught the site that is inside the iframe?

I'm asking this because the src value is always the same! It don't change even if you navigate inside the iframe.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

easiest way is to use javascript to dynamicly refresh the `<iframe>` by setting the `src` to a given interval refresh rate.

Have a look at the below example

[dynamicly refresh iframe without refreshing current page](http://jsfiddle.net/Wandile/q22wp/)